Running Powershell commands using Paramiko in python in a remote Windows 7
I'm using paramiko in Python to send commands (and retrieve data) from another server.
When I send a Powershell command to Windows 10 server it all works OK.
But when sending this to Windows 7 it stuck indefinitely.
sending cmd command works OK in both OS types
my example:
ssh_client = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh_client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
ssh_client.connect(server_address, connect_port, server_username, server_password)

stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh_client.exec_command("powershell 'echo hello'")

# Trying to run any of the next lines is stuck on Windows7
exit_status: int = stdout.channel.recv_exit_status()
output = stdout.read().decode()
error = stderr.read().decode()

I also tried to use:
channel = ssh_client.invoke_shell()
channel.send("powershell 'echo hello'")
time.sleep(1)
output = ""
while channel.recv_ready():
    output += channel.recv(1024).decode('utf-8')

in that case, it is not stuck, but the output (in Wind7) is:
"\x1b[2J\x1b[2J\x1b[2J\x1b[1;1H\x1b[0;39;24;27;37;40mMicrosoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601]                                            \n
[2;1HCopyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.                 \n\n
[4;1Hbioimg@LVBT-PC C:\\Users\\bioimg>shell 'echo hello'                               
[4;32Hshell 'echo hello'                               
[4;33H\x1b[4;33Hhell 'echo hello'                               
[4;34H\x1b[4;34Hell 'echo hello'                               
[4;35H\x1b[4;35Hll 'echo hello'                               
[4;36H\x1b[4;36Hl 'echo hello'                              
[4;37H\x1b[4;37H 'echo hello'                              
[4;38H\x1b[4;38H'echo hello'                               
[4;39H\x1b[4;39Hecho hello'                               
[4;40H\x1b[4;40Hcho hello'                               
[4;41H\x1b[4;41Hho hello'                               
[4;42H\x1b[4;42Ho hello'                               
[4;43H\x1b[4;43H hello'                               
[4;44H\x1b[4;44Hhello'                               
[4;45H\x1b[4;45Hello'                               
[4;46H\x1b[4;46Hllo'                               
[4;47H\x1b[4;47Hlo'                               
[4;48H\x1b[4;48Ho'                               
[4;49H\x1b[4;49H'                               
[4;50H\x1b[4;50H"

Is there a way to solve it?
Thanks

text like \x1b[4;33 is special code to change color, move cursor, etc in Linux terminal but maybe it can be used also in Windows terminals. See  ANSI Escape Codes

For a start, use stdout.channel.set_combine_stderr(True) + output = stdout.readlines() to rule-out a possibility that the command hangs because output buffers fill-up.  See Paramiko ssh die/hang with big output.

@MartinPrikryl Thank you very much! Your answer is working. My output is minimal (less than 100 characters), so I still don't understand why it works, but I'll read about it in the documentation. If you add it as an answer, I can accept it.

By the way, I found the real problem with the help of your solution. It's not about the buffer size. For some reason, the code gets stuck when trying to read an error when there is no error. When an error occurs it works as expected. So with Windows 7 and PowerShell, you need to use a channel (and not the straightforward "exec_command") and check if there is an error before trying to read it (using "channel.recv_stderr_ready()").
